# SWT Mac OSX - Unread Message Count (like Mac Mail or Skype)

Tags: java, macos, swt

I've written an SWT app, that on Windows just sits in the System Tray and changes its icon with a message count. This is fine for Windows, but when it comes to the Mac i'd like to make it look a little more native.

I can get an icon to pop itself into the doc area, which is fine, but not i'd like to get an unread message count like those found on Skype or Mac Mail. Is there a way of doing this using SWT?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Snippet336.java, from [the SWT snippets page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/). TaskBar and TaskItem will do what you want. TaskItem#setOverlayText(String) will put a badge on your application's icon.